# How to link React Native app to PHP/MySQL backoffice's database?

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

I have a backoffice website in PHP which is functional, with a system of users management account that works well. And I'm trying to connect my react native app to this website with its database but no success.

My aim is to test on localhost if I can connect with the different users created in the backoffice and access to the different contents of the different users.

I tried to fetch as url : http::/localhost:8000 ; the IPv4 address of the wi-fi (same network device and laptop). Those doesn't work, I don't know what else to try.

Other information : I'm using MAMP as local development.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english... I hope I've been as clear as possible.

Comment: If you use react native and run the app on a smartphone , the localhost will be pointing to the device itself. Hence you should use either the IP address of the webserver (or the domain name) for access to your web server

Comment: Super it works now. Thank you. You put me in the right track.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice day